# Migrating password with custom hash algorithm

Tags: 8, migrations

I am trying to migrate data from a custom database which uses a different method to HASH the password.

```
password = md5(email + password + salt)
```

During the process of migration I face **two issues**.

**I )**    To differentiate the new register Drupal passwords from Old site passwords. I tried adding "OLD$" code to the old password using

```
  public function prepareRow(Row $row) {

    if ($value = $row->getSourceProperty('password')) {
      $row->setSourceProperty('password', 'OLD$' . $value);
    }

    return parent::prepareRow($row);
  }
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

**II )** To check the passwords with old hash, I read in a [blog post](https://blog.42mate.com/migrating-user-password-from-non-drupal-database-to-drupal-8/) that new service needs to be created by extending `PhpassHashedPassword`

```
public function check ($password, $hash) {

    if (substr($hash, 0, 2) == 'U$') {

      $stored_hash = substr($hash, 1);
      //
      // Here you use the same algorithm the old site has to hash passwords
      // and store it on $password.

      if (substr($stored_hash, 0, 3) == '$P$') {
        // A phpass password generated using md5. This is a password migrated with
        // md5_passwords = TRUE
        $computed_hash = $this->crypt('md5', $password, $stored_hash);
        return $computed_hash && Crypt::hashEquals($stored_hash, $computed_hash);
      }
    }
```

In my algorithm,  `password = md5(email + password + salt)` the salt and email ID are needed. How can I get the values in `check` function

Comment: You can't, it's not available to that function. The only way to make this work is to customize the login form completely so that you don't use the default authenticate service but your own API

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and saving me from wasting more time on this. Just need one clarification, Is there a way to migrate the MD5 passwords as it is without Drupal rehashing it?