# Migrate the MD5 passwords as it is without rehashing

Tags: 8, migrations

I am trying to migrate data from a custom database which uses a different method to HASH the password.

```
password = md5(email + password + salt)
```

[Berdir has suggested](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/254102/migrating-password-with-custom-hash-algorithm#comment310771_254102) me to create a new authenticate service API to login user based on the old algorithm instead of Drupal 8 standard password hashing.

**So, I want to migrate the MD5 passwords from a custom database  to be migrated as it is without Drupal 8 Migrate API rehashing it.**

Comment: Q+A isn’t a format that supports tutorials being written for terse requirements. Explain exactly what you’re trying to achieve, exactly what you’ve tried, exactly where you’re stuck, and exactly what you need help with. Make sure your post is as detailed as possible to avoid wasting others time in suggesting solutions you’ve already tried. Many thanks

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @clive . I have explained the details further